# WCF service metadata (wsdl) cannot be accessed: error 400

Tags: wcf, metadata, http-status-code-400, svc

I have a problem with WCF metadata on a new installation ( IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016)

Situation

- WCF service running fine (as it used to do on previous installation)
- Navigation (via browser) of wsdl is NO more possible, or better
- http://ServiceA/ServiceA.svc: yes (web page available) but link to xml not working (error 400 from IIS)
- https://ServiceA/ServiceA.svc: not even the page

  Moreover in the serviceMetadata it is stated to use https no http, that is in contrast with the behaviour just described.

Below an extract of web.config

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="...">
        <endpoint address="https://<fqdn>/ServiceA/ServiceA.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
                  name="WsHttpBinding"
                  contract="ServiceContracts.IServiceA">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
    ...
```

Could it be something linked to name resolution?
The PC name is AAAAAA, the FQDN is BBBBB.domain.ext

Thanks for any suggestion
L.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I was offline for a while. Tomorrow I will try to remove the endpoint address, as you suggested. I'm perplex because at the begnning I set relative path (/ServiceA/ServiceA.svc) and the svc was accessible, but it was not the service itself. Setting the full url, the situation has swapped (no svc, but service ok). I'll let you know. Meanwhile, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**The WCF service deployed in IIS does not need to set the endpoint address in web.config.**

Here is my demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
      -->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService25.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService25.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService25.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService25.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This is web.config. This project is a template project.

The base address of the WCF service in IIS is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ding. Thanks for your reply, I did as you suggested. 
Up to now the VM is running in beta (accessible via internal network) and it runs fine:
both svc navigation and service operational.

My doubt is when we'll go in production, because currently I can see ServiceA.svc
resolved with "https://[MACHINE_NAME]/ServiceA/ServiceA.svc" (setting address="" as you suggested)
so, in the open internet I think it will depend on how my Ops colleagues configure the DNS

Comment: We can also access it by IP address.

Comment: Hi. I'll know when I go in beta-production. Not immediatly. Don't worry, if your answer will definetly be the one, I'll be happy to mark it. Thanks